# Change double quotes to single quotes

Tags: jquery

I need to change double quotes (") to single quotes (') because of restriction on grunt settings. If i change double to single quotes, getting script error.

Can any one please help to change double to single quotes and error free?

```
$(".custom-item").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('a[data-slidesjs-item="' + $(this).attr("data-item") + '"]').trigger('click');
});
```

Complete script have to be within single quotes only. Thanks

Comment: you need to share us what you have tried... we do not provide a code conversion service....

Comment: This is the code i created for my gallery. But due to code restriction.. dont know how to change double code to single. When i change this to single quotes.. getting error

Comment: @venkatesha deos any answer help ?

Comment: You can escape double quotes in content with \ (so you have `\"` instead of `"`) if you use double quotes for the javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably had a error because you didn't escape symbols.
In order to use `'` as a character in a string, you need to escape it this way `\'` to distinguish it from string beginning \ end.

The following characters should be escaped in JavaScript:

- Horizontal Tab is replaced with `\t`
- Vertical Tab is replaced with `\v`
- Nul char is replaced with `\0`
- Backspace is replaced with `\b`
- Form feed is replaced with `\f`
- Newline is replaced with `\n`
- Carriage return is replaced with `\r`
- Single quote is replaced with `\'`
- Double quote is replaced with `\"`
- Backslash is replaced with `\\`

What about your case. You should have simply changed all JS quotes to single quotes, and string quote characters to `\'`. This code works for me:

```
$('.custom-item').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('a[data-slidesjs-item=\'' + $(this).attr('data-item') + '\']').trigger('click');
});
```

However, at StackOverflow people who ask questions like "do this for me, I couldn't do anything" are usually left without an answer. Consider this next time. You should have posted a code which generates a error. So that we had something to start from.

Comment: Hi Yeldar, Thanks for your comments and help.. My apologies to you.

Answer (score 1):

This also works fine.

```
$('.custom-item').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('a[data-slidesjs-item=' + $(this).attr('data-item') + ']').trigger('click');
 });
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tariquasar/9fgq91cf/)